# Access voilation exception when trying to rewrite jmp

Tags: c++, windows, exception, assembly, hook

I have a game, I disasembled it and located a jump which I want to rewrite,

but whenever I try to write to the address I get a access voilation exception, even when I use VirtualProtect and set the READWRITE permission.

the instruction on 0x0042BD5F is this:

0x0046AACF E9 FF FF 89 FC | jmp some address here

Now, when I try to write to 0x0042BD5F, to change the relative jump address, I get an access voilation exception.

How do I change the jump on that address?

Code was requested, so here it is:

```
#define AddVar(Type,Name,Address) Type& Name = *reinterpret_cast<Type*>(Address)
/*
Hooker
1b 0x0042BD5F == E9 <relative jmp>
4b 0x0042BD60 - relative jump offset (always the value 0xFFFF89FC)
*/
AddVar(uqbyte, jump_hook_bytes, 0x0042BD60);
//the user tick function
void(*tick)(void);
void SetTick(void(*passed)(void))
{
    tick = passed;
}
void Ticker();
void OnDLLLoad(void(*passed)(void) = nullptr)
{
    tick = passed;
    //point the game loop end to Ticker()
    //replace the jump address
    //jmp (DESTINATION_RVA - CURRENT_RVA - 5 [sizeof(E9 xx xx xx xx)])
    DWORD old;
    VirtualProtect(
        (LPVOID)0x0042BD5F,
        0x05,
        PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_EXECUTE_READ | PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,
        &old
        );
    jump_hook_bytes = (((uqbyte)((uqbyte*)&Ticker) - (uqbyte)0x0042BD5F) - (uqbyte)0x0000005);
}
void Ticker()
{
    if (tick != nullptr)
    {
        tick();
    }
    __asm
    { 
        MOV EAX, 0x0042B9EA;//old address
        JMP EAX;
    }
}
```

`uqbyte` is an `unsigned long`.

When calling getlasterror the code seems to return the decimal error 87 (INVALID_PARAMETERS).

Comment: You could write a program to copy all the binary data before the address, change the address and copy everything after.  That will give you a new binary: provided there are no checksums otherwise it will mark your binary as invalid.

Comment: What have you tried?  Show your code.  Keep in mind that modern versions of Windows load a program's code at a different address each time the program is run.

Comment: No need to worry, the addresses always stay the same for functions. at least in this binary.

Comment: You never check whether VirtualProtect succeeded.

Comment: hm it fails but GetLastError returns 0

Comment: What are you trying to do? You don't write anything to 0x0042BD5F so why unprotect it? No wonder it crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366786.aspx) for the memory protection constants says:

> The following are the memory-protection options; you must specify one of the following values when allocating or protecting a page in memory.

It then lists a number of values, including the three that you combined together. When the documentation says "specify one of the following values" it means exactly one. You must not combine them.

You need to use `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` on its own.

I recommend that you add error checking around all your API calls. I also think that you could avoid hard coding the addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a debugger or a program that enables the process token privilege for debugger mode (like a trainer). I assume this isn't being used for an online cheat (offline shouldn't matter).

Comment: and how do I enable that process token? and online is kinda hard if what I'm making IS a multiplayer :P (so ye I'm editing 'offline' things). Game doesn't have a multiplayer for TCP/IP

Comment: If the goal is just to modify a jump, then why not use a trainer or a trainer maker kit? Enabling a process token requires getting the current process id, then getting tokens and looping to find the token for debugger, then enabling it. Then you need to determine the process id of the process that you're trying to modify.

Comment: @rcgldr He's trying to modify code in his own process. It's a detour.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `PAGE_EXECUTE | PAGE_EXECUTE_READ | PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` is wrong, you need to pass  `PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE` only to Virtual Protect. Now it works.